# Do I need to mention the coroutine dispatcher while working with Retrofit and Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

Recently I saw this - `Most data sources already provide main-safe APIs like the suspend method calls provided by Room or Retrofit. Your repository can take advantage of these APIs when they are available.`

What does this mean? Is the dispatcher under the hood `Dispatcher.IO` for Retrofit and Room? Or do I need to mention that explicitly, while making the request? Thank you.

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // Some retrofit call or room query
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No you don't need to mention dispatchers for Retrofit and Room. For Room when you mark a dao function as suspend fun it is guaranteed that it will not block main thread.

You can read this article https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5

from the article

> Room calls the `CoroutinesRoom.execute` suspend function, which switches to a background dispatcher, depending on whether the database is opened and we are in a transaction or not.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any reference for retrofit too? I look retrofit source codes, though I can't find any dispatcher thing there))

Comment: No but at github they are announcing retrofit supports suspend modifier in version 2.6.0 -> https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-260-2019-06-05 
from the changle log: "Behind the scenes this behaves as if defined as fun user(...): Call<User> and then invoked with Call.enqueue. You can also return Response<User> for access to the response metadata."

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't need to switch context when calling `suspend` functions of Retrofit and Room. I'm not sure if they use `Dispatcher.IO` under the hood, maybe they use their custom context composed of thread pools, but it is guaranteed to be called in background thread.

For example you can call `suspend` Dao functions in `ViewModel` class like the following:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    val user dao.getCurrentUser()
    // Update UI using user
}
```

assuming `getCurrentUser()` is a `suspend` function:

```
suspend fun getCurrentUser(): User
```

Comment: would be really interesting to know if adding in a specific dispatcher actually has any significant impact on performance, perhaps causing these operations to perform on a worse thread, if that even makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Marking your Retrofit HTTP request methods and Room DAO query methods as `suspend` tells both respective libraries to do the asynchronous work for you, meaning that you don't have to explicitly change threads with Dispatchers.IO at all.

Furthermore, even when a Room DAO method isn't marked `suspend`, *but* it returns a value wrapped in an Observable such as Kotlin's `Flow`, or RxJava's `Flowable`, or Jetpack's `LiveData`, Room will then run those queries asynchronously for you as well. [As per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries).

That being said, you *should* still launch coroutines in that case, whenever you call your async, non-blocking methods with `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope` depending on where you're calling them from (Activity/Fragment or ViewModel) to  harness the full power of suspending functions. `lifecycleScope` and `viewModelScope` use Dispatchers.Main.immediate by default, as already stated, you will not need to change Dispatchers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the case of room, if I won't mark the DAO functions as suspend, it will simply crash if I won't specify a dispatcher IO.

Comment: Yes. The only case where Room will run non-suspend functions asynchronously for you is when it returns a value wrapped in an Observable, like Kotlin's Flow, RxJava's Flowable, and Jetpack's LiveData, otherwise, you'll have to specify Dispatchers.IO.